# extract part of column to make cp command

Tags: awk, sed

I wan to create copy command to copy files from one directory to just back of it with removing suffix date. There are multiple files are there.

eg file `LOAN.DAILY.20191204`

want to create command

```
cp LOAN.DAILY.20191204 ../LOAN.DAILY
```

My attempt

```
ls -lrt | awk ' /DAILY/{ print "cp " , $9 , "../" , sub(/\.20191204$/,""); $9 }'
```

getting output

```
cp  LOAN.DAILY.20191204 ../ 1
```

why this 1 is coming

Comment: You might be interested in checking out the _mass move and rename_ command [mmv](https://ss64.com/bash/mmv.html) which allows copying also.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in *.DAILY.* ; do cp "$file" ../"${file%.*}";  done
```

[`shopt -s nullglob`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204803/why-is-nullglob-not-default): To avoid any unecessary copies in case the glob doesn't get a match.

[`"${file%.*}"`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html): Shell's parameter expansion to strip off the everything from strings's end till the first matched `.` in reverse direction.

I can't recall better and shorter ways to do this, although I suppose there are many.

Comment: This is the proper way to do it. Without the `nullglob` setting, you can do: `for file in *20191204; do [[ -f "${file}" ]] && cp "${file}" ../"${file%20191204}"; done`. The difference to the above is the test if `$file` is an actual file (fixing nullglob) and I also defined the date clearly.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
ls *DAILY* |  sed -E 's#^(.*)\..*#cp & \1#'
```

and once the output has been checked use this version to enact the copy.

```
ls *DAILY* |  sed -E 's#^(.*)\..*#cp & \1#e'
```

or an alternative using GNU parallel:

```
parallel --dry-run cp {} {.} ::: *DAILY*
```

again, check the result and if all ok, use:

```
parallel cp {} {.} ::: *DAILY*
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html:

> As mentioned, the third argument to sub() must be a variable, field, or array element. Some versions of awk allow the third argument to be an expression that is not an lvalue. In such a case, sub() still searches for the pattern and returns zero or one, but the result of the substitution (if any) is thrown away because there is no place to put it.

This explains why you get a `1` in the output.

If you want to modify the value of the ninth column you need to specify it in the `sub` call:

```
ls -lrt | awk ' /DAILY/{ orig=$9; sub(/\.20191204$/,"", $9); print "cp " , orig , "../", $9 }'
```

In this command, the original value of `$9` is stored in a variable `orig`, then the date suffix is removed using `sub`, and finally the `cp` command is constructed using the old and new values.